# glGetTextureSubImage INVALID OPERATION

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I'm unable to make **glGetTextureSubImage** work. On the other hand, **glGetTextureImage** works fine for me.

Test code:

```
const unsigned int sizeX=16;
const unsigned int sizeY=16;

// Init texture.
unsigned int texId;
glCreateTextures (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texId);
if (texId == 0)
    return false;

glTextureStorage2D (texId, 1, GL_RGBA8, sizeX, sizeY);
CheckGlError ("glTextureStorage Error: ");       // OK

// Create simple image.
unsigned int bufSize = sizeX * sizeY * 4;
unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char [bufSize];
    // fill buffer with anything...

// Upload image to texture.
glTextureSubImage2D (texId, 0,  0,0,  sizeX,sizeY,  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  buffer);
CheckGlError ("glTextureSubImage Error: ");      // OK

// Test downloads.
glGetTextureImage (texId, 0,  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  bufSize, buffer);
CheckGlError ("glGetTextureImage Error: ");      // OK

glGetTextureSubImage (texId, 0,  0,0,0,  sizeX,sizeY,0,  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  bufSize, buffer);
CheckGlError ("glGetTextureSubImage Error: ");   // 0x502 (INVALID OPERATION)
```

I have tried all kinds of alternatives and always gives the same error, even to download a single pixel. Also tried typical solutions like GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT=1 or all the glTextureParameters that I have come up with, quite desperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is the wrong error code. It should be `GL_INVALID_VALUE`, because the `depth` parameter you passed in was 0. It should be 1, since you're extracting one depth layer.

Comment: Totally right. I can't believe I didn't try that one.